# Restoring phpbb forum from locally stored(not backup) files

Tags: backup, restore, forum, phpbb

I have downloaded phpbb forum folder to local system. I have all the files in the system. I didn't take any backup in any conventional ways. Now I want to restore my forum using these files. I have tried to install phpbb again and after wards tried replace forum folder with my local folder.

Problem: I have deleted my website from hosting account so database also deleted. Now I am not able to restore my from to previous status.

fortunately I have old backups. I am able to restore it to two weeks back. 
But I am thinking if I may have any luck as I have downloaded all the files while deleting my hosting account. I don't know where the data of posts and users will be stored. If they are stored in forums folder then I may have luck.
I have recently made big post to my forum which took my entire day. I want that post . It will be embarrassing to say to new members that theirs ids are not available.

I am using plesk windows for hosting.

Please help in this regard. 
phpbb version: 3.0.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posts are stored in the database. There is no way to restore them from the forum files.

Comment: if you have deleted the database from your hosting account, then your 2 week old backup is the best you will get. If you just deleted the files from your host via ftp or the hosts file manager your database may still be there.